# Dev Ops Pipeline Job fails on task 'publish' with error "The process '/usr/bin/dotnet' failed with exit code 1"

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

After updating my API TargetFramework from 2.1 to 5.0, and pushing it to pipelines, I get the following result:

[image: Screenshots pipeline console]

The error says: error MSB3191: Unable to create directory "/home/vsts/work/1/a/MyAPI/". The file '/home/vsts/work/1/a/MyAPI' already exists.

Does anyone know at what I should look at? I'm not very familiar with pipelines yet.

My YAML file looks like this:

```
trigger:
    - master
    
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  
variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: 'MyAPI/MyAPI/MyAPI.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
     command: 'publish'
     publishWebProjects: True
     arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
     zipAfterPublish: True
     packageType: 'sdk'
     version: '5.0.101'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    contents: '*'
    targetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    pathToPublish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
    artifactName: MyBuildOutputs
```

Comment: Can you add you whole pipeline?

Comment: Uhm sorry, do you mean the full YAML file, or all the console logs before the problem happened?

Comment: I mean full YAML.

Comment: Yes, I have now updated my question with the full YAML file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove `--output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` from your build step and you also don't need `CopyFiles@2` as you publish to `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`

Comment: Thank you! It worked! I was struggling with this for 1.5 days now, so yeah... thanks a lot!